# Grails referencing of XSL Templates and Transformation

Tags: xslt, grails

Trying to do some transformation with Grails and wondering on the referencing issues. 
I have hosted the templates under "/WEB-INF/xslt/{file}.xsl" and I noticed that the files have import references to other files
Something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:i18n="http://apache.org/cocoon/i18n/2.1">
<xsl:import href="file2.xsl"/>
<xsl:import href="../xslt/file2.xsl"/>
```

I am aware of the fact that such is not the correct referencing and I was wonder how should I reference the xsl resources from the main xsl file to be imported when the transformation is required.

I am processing them throught he following code:

```
def String resources = grailsApplication.mainContext.getResource('/WEB-INF/xslt/'+xslTemplateName).file    
def String xslt = new File(resources).text
def factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance()
def transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xslt)))
```

Comment: Have you considered [freemarker](http://freemarker.org/) instead of XSL? It has great [XML](http://freemarker.org/docs/xgui_imperative_learn.html) support, including [xpath](http://freemarker.org/docs/xgui_imperative_learn.html#autoid_72) and you can inject java helper objects and invoke utility methods. I find it's much easier to read and maintain and far less verbose than XSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using relative URIs in imports, the problem is that by loading the content of the XSLT file yourself and then creating the `Transformer` from a `new StreamSource(Reader)`, the `Transformer` has no knowledge of the URL it was loaded from, and so no way to resolve the relative URIs correctly.  Instead you should use one of the `StreamSource` constructors that takes a `systemId`, e.g.

```
def xslResource = grailsApplication.mainContext.getResource(
    '/WEB-INF/xslt/'+xslTemplateName)

StreamSource xslSource = new StreamSource(xslResource.getInputStream(),
    xslResource.getURL().toString())
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslSource)
```

Note also that you should let the `TransformerFactory` read the resource's `InputStream` directly so the XML parser can detect and use the correct character encoding to load the file.  When you do `File.text` it always uses the default encoding for the current platform, which may not be the same as the encoding of the file as given by the `<?xml?>` declaration.

Comment: Thx for the answer.
Still cannot compile stylesheet but getting close. I noticed that the URL (xslResource. getURL()) is wrong. It is actually jndi:/localhost/mycontext/xslt/xsdFulltext.xsl and it is missing the port (8080) in this case.

Comment: @Armand the URL you get from `getResource` is only intended to be resolvable within the web application's own code, it's not supposed to be web accessible (because typically you use getResource to access things under `WEB-INF`, which _must not_ be web accessible according to the servlet spec).